# how to find out the duplicates and count them in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have an sqlite table like Results and want to make a table like finalResults by counting the number of options. i am using sqlite

```
   Table Name: Results           Table Name: finalResults
   ___________ _________         __________  _______  ________  _______  _______
    questionId| optionId         questionId| option1 | option2 |option3 |option4
    --------------------         -----------------------------------------------    
       40     | 3                40        | 1       |  2      | 4     | 1
       40     | 3                41        | 2       |  1      | 1      | 3
       40     | 2
       40     | 4
       40     | 2
       40     | 1
       40     | 3
       40     | 3
       41     | 1
       41     | 3
       41     | 2
       41     | 4
       41     | 4
       41     | 4
       41     | 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
INSERT INTO finalResults(questionId, option1, option2, option3, option4)
SELECT questionId,
       MIN(CASE WHEN optionid = 1 THEN n END) option1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN optionid = 2 THEN n END) option2,
       MIN(CASE WHEN optionid = 3 THEN n END) option3,
       MIN(CASE WHEN optionid = 4 THEN n END) option4
  FROM
(
  SELECT questionId, optionid, COUNT(*) n
    FROM results
   GROUP BY questionId, optionid
) q
 GROUP BY questionId
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fd6f3/1)** demo

or

```
INSERT INTO finalResults(questionId, option1, option2, option3, option4)
SELECT questionId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN optionid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) option1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN optionid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) option2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN optionid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) option3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN optionid = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) option4
  FROM results 
 GROUP BY questionId
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5af4f/1)** demo

Output in both cases:

```
| questionId | option1 | option2 | option3 | option4 |
------------------------------------------------------
|         40 |       1 |       2 |       4 |       1 |
|         41 |       2 |       1 |       1 |       3 |
```

Comment: @peterm-Thanks for quick reply...bt the finalResult table doesnot have any insertion after completion of query....

Comment: @VivekSehrawat Just use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax to insert pivoted results into finalResults. See updated answer and sqlfiddle example.

Comment: @peterm- sorry bt the table still doesn't have data in their fields

Comment: Did you take a look at sqlfiddle examples that I provided? What do you mean *...table still doesn't have data in their fields...*? Did you create `finalResults` table? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

try following query

```
select questionId,
sum(optionId==1) as option1,
sum(optionId==2) as option2,
sum(optionId==3) as option3
from results
group by questionId
```

or sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/415b7/6 (open into chrome & safari)